# Groupby match into list of lists

Tags: python-2.7

I have two lists that have matching elements. For example:

`L1 = [A, B] 
 L2 = [1_A, i_X, i_Y, 2_A, x_B, y_B, z_B]`

I wish to group the matching factors into new list like the following:

```
match_grouplist = [[1_A, 2_A],[x_B, y_B, z_B]]
```

I tried,

```
pull = []; tmp = []   
for entry in range(len(L1)):
        spp = L[entry]
        for ele in L2:
            if ele.split("_")[1] == spp:
                tmp.append(ele) 
         pull.extend(tmp)
```

It produces only a list. Can anyone suggest how to make this a list of list ?

Thanks in Advance,

AP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using list comprehensions :

```
[ [e2 for e2 in L2 if e2.endswith('_'+e1)] for e1 in L1 ]
```

This means that for each element e1 of L1 we will look for the elements of L2 that end with _e1, and return it.

The result is `[['1_A', '2_A'], ['x_B', 'y_B', 'z_B']]`

Comment: Hi, Why my solution did not work?. By basics, I stored it in list and restoring the list into another list. Hence it should be creating list of lists right?

Comment: @Arun I see two problems in your code.
- the result is not a list of lists because you use `extend` to add the results to _pull_, instead of `append`. `extend` adds the elements of _tmp_ in the list _pull_
- _tmp_ should be reset in the first loop. With this code the results for the first element of L1 are kept for the second element, leading to `['1_A', '2_A', '1_A', '2_A', ....]`